# Can we make supervisord's stdout_logfile as named pipe files instead normal file?

Tags: linux, file, named-pipes, supervisord

I am exploring supervisord and need to redirect logs to a file. I can achieve this with a simple config but I am looking to use named pipe file for stdout_logfile field instead a normal file.

```
command={command}
priority=900
autorestart=true
startsecs=5
startretries=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/raw.log
```

I know **/tmp/raw.log** file is a normal file but looking for a way to *replace this with a named pipe file (FIFO file)*.

Any help, suggestion pointer to a right document would be helpful.

Comment: `stdout_logfile=/the/path/to/your/fifo/file` ? For example `stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout`.

Comment: I did simple testing by creating a named pipe file and assigning it to stdout_logfile in supervisor.d conf. It didn't work

Comment: `It didn't work` How do you know? Did you get any error message?  Did supervisord started or crashed? Were you listening on the pipe? What happened, what did not happen. Please post the exact error message and all the steps needed to reproduce it.

Comment: supervisord overriden the named pipe with regular file. you can run ls -l command and see if file if of FIFO or regular.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple testing and found that supervisors overrides the named file (FIFO) with a regular file.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a FIFO file with command -> mkfifo file_path
2. Run some program with supervisored and redirect the log to created FIFO file
3. Validate the file type by command ls -l